# This site can’t be reached when deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I have a simple MERN app developed and working locally. However I have "site can not be reached" after deploying to Heroku.

Here are my Heroku logs:

```
2019-09-12T00:33:00.665358+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-09-12T00:33:03.909328+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-09-12T00:33:03.909347+00:00 app[web.1]: > myStreet@1.0.0 start /app
2019-09-12T00:33:03.909349+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-09-12T00:33:03.909351+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-09-12T00:33:05.050233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-09-12T00:33:04.994283+00:00 app[web.1]: LISTENING ON PORT 3001
2019-09-12T00:33:05.082318+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
2019-09-12T00:33:05.229315+00:00 app[web.1]: connected to the database
2019-09-12T00:33:12.960721+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 404 4.000 ms - 139
2019-09-12T00:33:12.960048+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dry-hamlet-33823.herokuapp.com request_id=d8a5cd47-50fa-428a-92d0-97ccba40db05 fwd="65.95.137.53" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=404 bytes=415 protocol=https
```

What's the problem, and how can I fix it? I used the process.env.PORT to set the port.

============
Thanks for everyone's help,I solved the issue via watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1LaekAnVIMo

Comment: Can you post your server JS page? Or if you have a git repo with the code.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> LISTENING ON PORT 3001
> ```

This is almost certainly an error.

You don't get to pick your port on Heroku: it [sets an environment variable `PORT`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers) that you must use when starting your server. While it's *possible* that Heroku gave you port 3001 that seems unlikely.

This [sample Node.js application](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/blob/787a0397af4e2a295607cced85aa882931c18d3d/index.js#L3) gives an example of how to use the `PORT` environment variable with Express.

Comment: I did use the process.env.PORT in the code. However, I am not able to have the REACT app working on Heroku.  Git repo: https://github.com/mail2mz/myStreet

Comment: @mikezenon, then why does it say "listening on port 3001", when 3001 is your default value? Are you sure that you're running the same code you linked to? _Specifically_, what do you mean by "I am not able to have the React app working"? Please see [ask].

Comment: Yes, I pushed my local git to the link I sent and Heroku. It is a simple MERN stack example. It has React as front end, Node.js as backend. The port 3001 is the port that backend is listening.

Comment: "The port 3001 is the port that backend is listening"—again, _you don't get to decide this_. Heroku gives you _one_ port you can use. You don't get to use more than one, and you don't get to pick what port you use.

Comment: I am using the option1. https://coursework.vschool.io/deploying-mern-with-heroku/

Comment: @mikezenon, please read [ask]. We're not going to go off-site just to understand what you're trying to ask. Questions should be self-contained. Links are fine for supplementary information. So, what what is "option 1"?

Comment: Keep them together – Express and React files sit on the same machine (with all the React files inside a specific client folder), and Express does double duty: serving the React files and also serving API requests.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku sets the PORT as an environment variable. So change the code accordingly.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('LISTENING ON PORT ' + port);
});
```